# Visual Studio 2005 vs. 2008 ....can't see the code the designer automatically generates in 08 like in 05?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

So I am a beginner with .NET, Visual Studio, C#, etc. But I am wondering something about the code behind a form and a difference I am seeing in 2008 versus 2005.

So lets say I have a simple Windows Form app, C#, and I throw a couple controls on it. Then I add some MessageBox.Show event handlers for the default events....in 2005 there is that little section within the code that is hidden that basically contains the code that 'registers' the controls with the system....I think. That may be a bad definition?? Basically I think that automatic code generated here just basically associates the event to the event handling code....anyway.

I can see this is 2005 (once I click the like gray box), but it does not appear anywhere in 2008. So this has to exist somewhere, and I just wanted to ask to be familiar with what is going on since I am new to this. I still have to figure out how to turn on the code line numbering in 2008, but I can google it.

Thanks for the help!
Justin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in a separate `FormName.Designer.cs` file using [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx):

[image]

Comment: So...that was easy. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you click the "View-->Solution Explorer" menu in the visual studio menu bar, it should bring the solution/project files listing.  Once you're there find your form and click the little plus sign next to it to expand the files below it.  It should look something like:

YourForm.Designer.cs (designer file) - double-click it to open it

Yourform.resx (embedded resources file, this may or may not be there) - you can also view this in the designer or code behind (xml)

To view the code behind (where the event definitions are contained), right-click your form and select "View Code".  This should bring up the code-behind you're looking for.